# Perform a load image on slide for jquery carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I need to reload an image when a slide show as it is an animated gif and needs start at the beginning

I can do it on click using an if statement on the current class but this is not the way I need it as I want it to load as soon as the slide comes in.  So far I have the below

```
this.$slides.eq(this.current).addClass('da-slide-current');

var image = new Image();
image.src = "kick.gif";

$("div").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("da-slide-current")) {
        $(this)
        $('.da-slide-current > .da-img > img').attr('src', image.src);

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = "kick.gif";

this.$slides.eq(this.current)
    .addClass('da-slide-current')
    .find("> .da-img > img").attr('src', image.src);
```

Comment: thanks but this only works onload, not when the slide comes in, so if the image is on slide 2 it doesn't fire

Comment: can you please show your full code or create a [fiddle](http://fiddle.net)? I can't tell how you are switching slides

Comment: I'm using the codedrops parallax slider (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/), here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/JkRwv/1/